# Failed to retrieve services of a CBPeripheral after restart the peripheral

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral

I have a problem while trying to reconnect with a paired peripheral, it connects but I can not find the services.

The steps are as follows.

1. Turn on the peripheral device and open app.

   - Find the peripheral after scan. OK
   - Connect to the peripheral. OK
   - Save peripheral id for future reconnection.
   - Find the services / Characteristics. OK
2. Now I disabled the bluetooth from IOS and turned it on again to test the reconnection.

   - Find the peripheral after scan. OK
   - Connect to the peripheral with saved id. OK
   - Find the services / Characteristics. OK
3. Now I closed the app and reopen to test again.

   - Find the peripheral after scan. OK
   - Connect to the peripheral with saved id. OK
   - Find the services / Characteristics. OK
4. Now turn off the peripheral and then turn on again.

   - Find the peripheral after scan. OK
   - Connect to the peripheral with saved id. OK
   - Find the services / Characteristics. DOES NOT WORK NEVER MORE.

After step 4 if i repeat steps 1,2 and 3 they will not find services, the problem is when I restart the peripheral.

I'm setting the `self.manager.delegate=self` and implementing `CBCentralManagerDelegate` and `CBPeripheralDelegate` correctly, and I'm using `self.manager.retrievePeripherals (withIdentifiers: [UUID])` to connect to the paired peripheral.

Any idea? I will be very grateful.

Comment: Why are you scanning after step 1?  Once you have the saved identifier you can `retrievePeripheral(withIdentifiers:)` and then just `connect`. How do you resolve the problem? Do you need to restart the iOS device? Forget the peripheral?

Comment: scan = I can find the peripheral.
After step 1 I'm using retrievePeripherals to find the peripheral.
To solve the problem I need to go into settings and forget the paired device.

Comment: @AndréPonce: did you ever solve this? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: @OlavJ Yes, I solved it. It was a firmware problem! After the hardware team updated the firmware everything worked perfectly. You can use third-party apps to view your peripheral services and test the reconnection, if that doesn't work well the problem may be in the firmware.